# Command works in JS console, but not in document.ready(function() { ... })

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of code whose purpose is simple: inject some HTML into a `div`. Because of privacy, I can't cut-paste-it exactly or post a link, but it's like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some-div').prepend('<div class="some-class"><img height="97" src="pic.jpg" width="183" /></div>');
});
```

It's doing anything, and I can't figure out why. When I paste `$('#some-div).prepend('<div class="some-class"><img height="97" src="pic.jpg" width="183" /></div>');` into the JS console, however, it does what I want it to do. What should I be checking for in order to figure out why this is?

Comment: That wasn't the problem ... That was a type-o when I made this post. Sorry.

Comment: Is this piece of code wrapped in any other function? If so, `$(document).ready()` might have already happened before, so it's not triggered. To check that, put a `console.log('test');` before `$(docu...`, and another one inside. If you only see one of them, that's your problem. If not, try dfsq's suggestion.

Comment: check webpage source if there is a programming error inside body. PHP or ASP errors (even resumed) can defer document ready state.

Comment: @blex, the code will still execute. From the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), *"If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately."*

Comment: Do a `console.log($('#some-div'))`. Are you sure the element exists, maybe it's loaded asynchronously?